# How could the php class pass the value back in this example

Tags: php, class

```
<?php
    class Apple
    {
        public function showColor()
        {
            return $this->color;
        }
    }

    class Banana
    {
        public $color;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->color = "Banana is yellow";
        }

        public function GetColor()
        {
            return Apple::showColor();
        }
    }

    $banana = new Banana;
    echo $banana->GetColor();
?>
```

I don't know how could the class Apple get $this->color from the Banana.

Comment: Huh ... ?? Where is defined the color in Apple ?

Comment: Also you are using a static call inside GetColor() and the showColor() is non static... bad way to code

Comment: there is no definition of color in the apple but if u run this code, the output is Banana is yellow, which means the color has been passed to class Apple

Answer (score 0):

Banana class:

```
 public function GetColor()
            {
                return Apple::showColor($this);
            }
```

Apple class:

```
public static function showColor($banana)
        {
            return $banana->color;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is really wrong in your code.

Syntaxically, your code is not good.

It should be something like this:

```
<?php
    class Apple
    {
        public function showColor()
        {
            return $this->color;
        }
    }

    class Banana
    {
        public $color;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->color = "Banana is yellow";
        }

        public function GetColor()
        {
            $apple = new Apple();
            return $apple->showColor();
        }
    }

    $banana = new Banana;
    var_dump($banana->GetColor());
?>
```

With this good syntax, you are not able to get any values because no colors are defined in Apple class.

Comment: thank you for your reply if you run my code you will get the values: banana is yellow. that is my question how could the $color  could be passed to showcolor()

Comment: Well I cannot really tell you as I am not expert, but the fact is as the code syntax is wrong, you should fix it instead of understand why you get the value.

Comment: @JingweiHu To pass the variable to a function, you need to add it to the argument list of the function!! as @DannyPhantom [have already suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32262606/3709765) :) However, the semantics and the logic of your code doesn't seem like to be in the direction of good programming practices! I mean, a `Banana` class should not get it's color value from an `Apple` class, or perhaps you meant to do sth else and maybe have used some unrelated semantics!!

Comment: @someOne generally i won't code like this syntax, cuz when i write the php code ,the normal programming logic will follow my C++ programming habit. However, i found someone 's code was written in this syntax and worked well, which triggered my interest

Answer (score 0):

This is how the `Apple` class gets the `color` from the `Banana` class:
Actually, if you run the code having the `E_STRICT` error reports turned on, a warning is generated saying:

> Non-static method `Apple::showColor()` should not be called statically,
>   assuming `$this` from incompatible context in ...

This means that the PHP interpreter casts the `$this` of the `Banana` type to an incompatible `Apple` object. The *"incompatible type casting"* is just like renaming the type-name of `Banana` to the type-name of `Apple`! The `$this` (of type `Banana`) has the field of `color`, so does the new casted object of type `Apple`.

Conceptually, this is what the interpreter does:

```
class Banana
{
    .
    .
    .
    public function GetColor()
    {
        $apple = cast($this, 'Apple'); // There is no such a cast() function in PHP,
                                       // it is for demonstration purposes only!
                                       // The $apple now has what $this already have!!
        return $apple->showColor();
    }
}
```